# apply different fragment shaders in to 2 different images on the same canvas

Tags: webgl

I am drawing two images into a canvas and I need to apply different webgl fragment shader on these two images. let us say invert color on the first image and brightens on the second one.  what is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Did you look into [rendering to a texture](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1786)? ([another post](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html))

Comment: Ask "what's the best way" is an opinion question and SO suggests it should be closed. Typically if you want to do something different in a shader you use another shader. [You might find this answer helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442362/webgl-javascript-object-transformations-with-multiple-objects/26444813#26444813) or [this article](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html).

Comment: Sorry, i am new to webgl, but my problem is i need a way to apply 2 shaders into two images drawn on one canvas which has one webgl context, for now if i used another shader it will apply to both images. So what i dis is just to create two canvses , to solve this issue but its not effiecient,