# WebGL- Issue when rendering one shape after another

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, webgl

I've been following along with a [WebGL tutorial series](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1253) and the point I'm at in the series deals with applying both textures and lighting to a 3D sphere. In order to actually grasp the proper implementation of such programs so I can write them in the future, I'm trying to implement a version of the code without the lighting and textures. I've been able to draw 3D parametric shapes before where one was drawn on a canvas at a time (using a different setup) so I'm essentially adding that code into the [**program**](https://github.com/tparisi/webgl-lessons/blob/master/lesson11/index.html) provided from the tutorial. The tutorial code follows a structure where there is function named `webGLStart()` that is called when the page loads which itself calls `initGL()` (which sets up the canvas), `initShaders()`, `initBuffers()` (for the shapes to be drawn), and ``drawScene()```.

I've able to successfully draw one shape in the middle of the canvas, but for some reason, when I try to subsequently draw another shape, I'm getting the error: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` on the line where I translate the model view matrix to the position for the new shape. Following the methods from the tutorial, there is an array used as a stack to save the current state of the mvMatrix before a transformation for each shape and the state is restored after the last transformation has been performed on each shape. I was thinking that maybe the current copy of the mvMatrix wasn't getting popped properly after the first shape was drawn as after some debugging, it seems that there are the same amount of stack frames before and after the pop. I don't think this is causing the error, but it was the only possible problem I could find.

I'm pretty sure I am setting up the buffers for each shape properly as I am doing essentially what was done in the tutorial [**source code**](https://github.com/gpjt/webgl-lessons/blob/master/lesson04/index.html)  so I have no idea what is going wrong. I have a snippet (but still very long segment) of  [**my code here**](https://gist.github.com/loremIpsum1771/5575ac68c9d49fa7eec4) for the `initBuffers()` and `drawScene()` functions.

What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebGL/Javascript: Object transformations with multiple objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442362/webgl-javascript-object-transformations-with-multiple-objects)

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614956/webgl-adding-multiple-objects-to-one-canvas and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009328/drawing-many-shapes-in-webgl. You might find [these tutorials helpful](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links, actually the problem was that I left out a parameter of the translate function before the second shape was drawn * facepalm *  I do have another problem though but I should be able to work through that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was correct except that there was a parameter left out of the `translate()` function before the shape was drawn.